# FB JS SDK, is there a way to detect if a user has liked your page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

If a user has liked a page, I would like to remove the live button. How do you do this?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to test for whether a user likes a particular page or not in a programmatic way, it can be done like this:

Note that it will require you to ask for the "user_likes" permission from the user in your O-Auth connect dialog.

This code snippet will test for whether someone currently likes something or not:

```
    FB.api('/me/likes/MY_PAGE_ID', {limit: 1}, function(r) { 
        if (r.data.length == 1) {
            //do stuff when the user is a liker
        } else {
            //do stuff when the user is not currently a liker           
        }
    });
```

If you want to catch the event when the user clicks the like button, then you can use FB.Event.subscribe:

```
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
         function(response) {
              //Do stuff when the user just clicked a "like" button
         }
    );
```

Comment: see here for unlike: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990594/unlike-event-similar-to-edge-create

Comment: I know the question is about the js sdk but there is a better way to detect whether a user has likes your page or not using php and it dosnt require asking the user for any permissions. Facebook sends the whether the page is liked along with other useful data to every page tab via the signed_request. I have written a tutorial and included a simple php class for download which can be found here -> http://www.fryed.co.uk/blog/how-to-detect-if-someone-likes-your-facebook-page hope its of use.

Answer (score 0):

You should use xfbml version of Like-box. Subscribe to event: edge.create http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/
When a user click like in like-box, that function callback send URL of your Facebook page. Next, you can add javascript to hide like-box and set cookie of user-liked

Comment: Any way to do this without needing a cookie, somehow check with some api call?